Perturbations around Minkowski in xPert
I want to be able to perform perturbations in Minkowski space using xPert, xTras, and of course xAct. I am trying to re-create the parity even term found in this paper: Causality Constrains Higher Curvature
Corrections to Gravity namely the first term in equation 5. Here is my current setup. I believe I entered the action correctly, namely $(\text{Riem})^4$ in the manner they wrote it, but I think I am wrong and the contractions should actually be $R_{abcd}R^{cdef}R_{efgh}R^{ghab}$, but I am just going off of the paper. I entered it into Mathematica as
DefManifold[M, dim, IndexRange[a, q]]
DefMetricPerturbation /. Options@DefMetric
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g", CurvatureRelations -> True]
S4 = \[Alpha]*RiemannCD[a, b, c, d] RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, -d] RiemannCD[e, f, h, i] RiemannCD[-e, -f, -h, -i] /. dim -> 4

eomS4 = ToCanonical[CollectTensors@VarL[metric[-a, -b], CD][S4]]

This gives me the correct equations of motion (albeit, expanded so you have to check it yourself you are not missing any terms), and I find the perturbations in the following manner:
DefTensor[H[-a, -b], M, Symmetric[{-a, -b}]]
linearS4 = ExpandBackground[eomS4prime]
linearS4 /. Perturbationmetric[LI[1], inds__] :> H[inds] // ToCanonical // ContractMetric
% // Simplification // CollectTensors

The last line just puts it into a readable form (sort of). So, I have the following questions:

How can I impose $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ i.e. vacuum solution without making Riemann vanish?
How can I impose the transverse traceless condition on the perturbations namely $h = 0$ and $k_\mu h^{\mu\nu} = 0$ which for the computational purposes is simply $\partial_\mu h^{\mu\nu} = 0$ modulo a factor of $i$.
How can I distinguish between covariant derivatives with respect to the background and those not? Is there an identifier?
If I wanted to, how can I tell Mathematica to stop at some order in derivatives on the perturbations? For example, what if I only wanted second order derivatives of the perturbation, or even 0th order, but to preserve the derivatives on the Riemann tensor (as done in equation (6) of the paper linked above).

Any help or hints are useful since I am lost with this stuff, thanks!
EDIT: I figured out a cheap way to include the trace condition, at the end of the perturbed line, just include
/.H[,-]->0/.H[-,]->
This is obviously not pretty, but it does the trace property ok, but now I need to implement the transverse condition, which requires a symmetrized rule since if I did the same thing for the trace condition, Mathematica would not catch all the possible products.
